# Filter MYSQL results based on a LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, pdo

I am trying to filter results based on a left join so that IF the join is successful it only pulls the matching record. But I am just getting a blank result.

Table users

```
user_id | user_name
```

Table skills

```
skill_id | user_id | boss_id | date_acquired
```

The statement I am trying to use (PDO in PHP)

```
SELECT 
    users.user_id,
    users.user_name,
    skills.date_acquired
FROM 
    users
LEFT JOIN skills ON 
    users.user_id=skills.user_id 
    AND 
    boss_id=?
WHERE 
    user_id=?
```

In my execute statement I have insured that I have values for both parameters. I get the **user** but not the **date_acquired** field and I am sure there is an entry that matches the parameters. Am I joining incorrectly?

Comment: If you are expecting to only see records where there is a corrspoending record in 'skills' and the date_acquired attribute is always populated in this table, then you should be using an inner join. This query will return all users. But without a better explanation of your intention its pointless suggesting a more apposite solution.

Comment: I wonder... don't you get a "user_id is ambiguous in where clause" (or similar) error?

Comment: @symcbean sometimes there is not skill associated with the user so that is why left join.

Comment: @Tschitsch I do not get ambiguous clause in my actual SQL. It is quite lengthy so I published an example to make it easier.

Comment: Inverse the statement by selecting from `skills` first and left joining from the `users`.

Comment: @DanielH. Well, beside the already mentioned ambiguous user_id I don't see an issue with your query. Since you've ensured, that the data exists it must be something else, that is causing the empty set. You probably should provide more input, e.g. records on your tables, php-snippet where you prepare and execute the query.